# How to recover code after 'git push --set-upstream origin master'

Tags: git, git-reset

I was trying to push my code to a new repo but in typical git fashion, it's easy as rocket surgery to learn and implodes your code if you don't know every detail. Ok so I did something and now most of my code is gone so how do I undelete my code or get it back?

So how can I undo an error on bash git?

Why isn't there a "git undo" ?

What I typed in ( by accident ) was "git push --set-upstream origin master" now my code is wiped out. Well I am hoping its still in a folder but not shown for whatever 'because git' reason.

I've tried for three years to understand git and it still 90% gibberish to me.

'git reflog' is what google search is showing but it just shows me this info.

```
f668709 (HEAD, origin/master) HEAD@{0}: rebase: checkout origin/master
5061c5e (master) HEAD@{1}: commit (initial): first new commit
```

Comment: ```git push --set-upstream origin master```
Means that your current branch was set to track remote ```master``` branch and pushed there your commits.

Can you post here log of the master branch? (check it out and pull latest changes)
And also log of the branch that you have been on when you entered your command.

Comment: Did you commit your code before pushing ? what does `git status` show ?

Comment: @Monsieur Merso, your post is helpful. I did some research and found that 'git reset HEAD@{1} seems to show all the files that are gone. @ Dev-vruper 'git status' seems to show a long list of the files that I needed as 'deleted:'

This is confusing, since if it deleted why can I see a list of 3,345 files in 'git reset HEAD@{1}' which leads me to think it's just 'soft deleted' but they are still held in some magical box waiting for the right command? Hopefully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why isn't there a "git undo" ?

There is ... well, *sort of*.  There are a lot of catches here.

> What I typed in ( by accident ) was "git push --set-upstream origin master"

This makes no changes at all to any of your own commits in your own repository.  It's also a "safe" kind of push, so it should not wreck anything in the *other* Git repository, over at `origin`.  There should be nothing *to* undo.

If the push failed—and I suspect it did—you might then be encouraged by Git to run `git pull` or `git pull --rebase` or similar.  *This* might well be a mistake, though.

> I've tried for three years to understand git and it still 90% gibberish to me.

You might need a different approach. :-)  Are you familiar with graph theory?  If so—or even if not—consider perusing the web site [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).  But that's to be done after something more basic: realizing that Git often *hides* what *Git* has, and shows you something else entirely.

> 'git reflog' is what google search is showing but it just shows me this info.
>
> ```
> f668709 (HEAD, origin/master) HEAD@{0}: rebase: checkout origin/master
> 5061c5e (master) HEAD@{1}: commit (initial): first new commit
> ```

This strongly suggests (though does not by itself prove) that:

- your Git repository might only have two commits in it (it has at least two); and
- it's not the `git push origin master` that has caused the trouble, but rather a `git rebase`.

If you run `git status`, it will probably tell you that you are in the middle of a rebase.  You must have run something *after* the `git push origin master`.

If you *are* in the middle of a rebase, you can terminate the process and put things back the way they were with `git rebase --abort`.  Note, though, that if you have done some work you'd like to save, this `--abort` operation may throw it away: copy any files you want saved first!

## Long: where your files went

I'll write up a long-ish (not all that long for *me*) description here of where your files went, and where they come back from after `git rebase --abort`, assuming that they do come back.  I think, based on what you've said in your question, that they will.  You can jump down to the next section, but it's probably best to read through the whole thing.

#### What might be your first key to understanding Git

If you're going to use Git (nothing says you *have* to of course), it's probably wise to invest some time in understanding what it's doing, and why it's so obstreperous.  The reason is that Git isn't really about *files*.

When you do work, you probably work on and with files.  That's what your computer stores, after all: files, organized into directories / folders.  So you'd expect Git to work with these.  And it does—*sort of*.  But it insists on doing this *its* way.

What Git does instead is store *commits*.  These are numbered entities.  Your `git reflog` output here shows two commits:

- `5061c5e`: you made this one yourself, locally;
- `f668709`: someone—possibly *not* you—made this one, probably in some other Git repository.

These two commits *may or may not be related to each other*.  To find out, you can run `git log --all --decorate --graph`.  Commits that are related to each other get connected together, like this:

```
* commit 72c4083ddf91b489b7b7b812df67ee8842177d98 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
| Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
| Date:   Wed Jan 6 23:22:15 2021 -0800
| 
|     The first batch in 2.31 cycle
|     
|     Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
|   
*   commit d3aff11c3eadf3c496859180d453ce07cde72b44
|\  Merge: cf4b0714f7 5bc12c11cc
| | Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

(This kind of `git log` often shows the full commit numbers, rather than the more human-friendly<sup>1</sup> abbreviated ones you see in your `git reflog` output.)

What this shows is that commit `2c4083ddf...` is the *child* of earlier *parent* commit `d3aff11c3...`.  (The parent commit is itself a child of some older ancestors, which are children of still older ancestors, and so on.)

In the end, then, commits are *numbered*, with these big ugly strings of letters-and-digits, and can have some kind of family relationships.  That's all well and good, but still doesn't tell you what they are, or what good they are.

What a commit *is* comes in two parts.  *All parts of any commit are read-only:* nothing in any commit can ever be changed.  You *can* take a commit out of Git, work on / with it, and put back a modified version, but what you get is a *new* commit, with a new number.  The old commit, with the old number, remains, unchanged.  Meanwhile, the two parts are these:

- The main body of the commit is a saved snapshot of *every file that Git knew about*, as of the form it had *in Git* at the time you, or whoever, made it.  This is where we get files into Git: they live inside commits.  But you can't *see* these files directly.

  One reason for that is that they're not stored the same way that your computer stores files.  Instead, they're compressed and frozen, and—so that your Git repository doesn't quickly grow hugely fat—*de-duplicated*.  Most commits mostly re-use most of their files from some previous commit.  So, instead of putting a new copy of each file into each new commit, Git arranges for the underlying file data to be *shared* across *all* commits.

  Git lets the exact mechanism for this sharing show through in various places.  That can be either good or bad, depending on your taste for seeing implementation details of what should otherwise just be abstractions.  To keep this answer from getting too long, I won't go into any detail about that here; just keep in mind that Git tends to be overly proud of its details, whacking you in the face with them now and then.  We'll see this again in a moment with Git's *index*.
- The rest of the commit—the part that's actually stored *as* the commit; the files are stored indirectly to achieve the de-duplication trick—contains metadata: information about the commit itself, such as who made it, when, and the log message saying why they made it.

  The "family relationships" of commits are stored in this metadata.  The way Git achieves this is to store the *commit number* of this commit's parents.  Everything else must be deduced from this *I am the child of ____* stuff stored in each commit.<sup>2</sup>

So, commits allow you to store files—in fact, they require you to save *every* file, forever—and also store metadata including parentage.  This is where *branches* come in.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or perhaps I should say *slightly less human-hostile*.

<sup>2</sup>You might wonder why parents don't record their children.  That's because of this read-only aspect of commits.  When we make a new commit—a child of some parent—the child knows who its parent is.  But when we make the child, we don't yet know what *its* children will be.  They will get a unique, random-looking hash-ID number later.  The actual numbers aren't random at all: they are cryptographic checksums of the contents of the commit.  But they *are* unpredictable, because, for instance, the commits include those time-stamps.  You would have to know *when* you will make a child commit, as well as everything else that will be in it, to predict its hash ID.  (There's another catch as well, but that alone is hard enough.)

---

#### Branches are just a way to remember commit numbers

When you make the very first commit—in your case, `5061c5e` (for which you gave the log message `first new commit`)—it's stand-alone.  It's just a snapshot of all the files you told Git about, using `git add`.  It gets a big ugly hash ID, unique to this particular commit, never to be used anywhere in any Git repository ever again.  This one is `5061c5e` for short here, but let's go even shorter and call it "commit `A`", and draw it:

```
A
```

If you were to change some files, `git add` them, and run `git commit` again, this would make a *new* snapshot of every file—all the files that were in `A`, updated by whatever you changed and then `git add`-ed—and make a new commit out of that.  The *parent* of the new commit, which we'll just call `B` for short, will be existing commit `A`, so that `B` holds `A`'s hash-ID number (`5061c5e`) inside its metadata.

We say that commit `B` *points to* commit `A` and draw that like this:

```
A <-B
```

As we add more and more commits, we build up a simple backwards-looking chain of commits:

```
A <-B <-C <-D
```

Now, the trick here is that Git can only *find* commits *by their hash-ID numbers*, at the lowest levels of Git.  But the numbers are pretty human-hostile, even when abbreviated.  That's why I've been using letters!  If we had to tell Git the raw number of commit `D` just to use it, that would be intolerable.  So Git adds, to the collection of *commits* and supporting stuff that it saves, a set of *names*.  These are names like `master`: *branch* names, for instance.<sup>3</sup>  Git chooses to have these names store exactly one hash ID.  Since commit `D` is, in our illustration here, the *last* commit on `master`, that's the *number* that the name will store:

```
A <-B <-C <-D   <--master
```

Whenever we make a *new* commit, Git:

1. makes the new commit point back to the current commit: new commit `E` will point to `D`; then
2. writes the *new* commit's number into the branch name

so that if we make a new commit `E` we end up with:

```
A <-B <-C <-D <-E   <--master
```

This is how we *grow* a branch, one commit at a time.  We use `git checkout` or `git switch` to select the branch *name* and thereby the *last commit on the branch*, to which the name itself points.

---

A branch name like `master` is actually short for a longer "full name": `refs/heads/master`.  This allows Git to use the same storage system for *tag* names, which go under `refs/tags/`, and other kinds of names.

---

## Where your files went

Let's go back a moment and consider those commits.  Each one stores *all* your files, but in a peculiar, twisted-up, read-only, de-duplicated fashion.  These files are literally impossible to work with.  They're only good as *archives*.  They have to be *extracted* before you can work on or with them.

Extracting these files, then, is at least part of what many Git commands are about.  The most obvious one of these is `git checkout`.  We can `git checkout` a *branch name*, or we can use something that's *not* a branch name—including the raw hash ID number of any historical commit—to `git checkout` that historical commit.

To do this, Git needs an area it can *fill in* from a commit.  That area is also where you will do your work.  This work area *is* **yours**, most of the time.  But when you use `git checkout`, or other Git commands that explicitly *overwrite* your work area files, you're telling Git: *Remove the files I have here now, and replace them with other files.*

Some Git commands are careful, when doing this, not to wreck any *uncommitted* files.  Others will cheerfully wreck all your unsaved files if you tell them to.  Fortunately the commands you're using here are almost certainly the safer varieties.<sup>4</sup>

Anyway, we call this area where you work, your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  Here, your files are *files*.  They have their ordinary everyday form.  You can actually *use* them (imagine that!).

If you have used (the safe version of) `git checkout` to pick some *commit* to work *from*, Git has filled in your work-tree from the saved files *in* that commit.  The `git rebase` command does that, at the start of a rebase.  What happened to the files you *wanted* to have is that they're safely stored in the *other* commit: commit `5061c5e`.  You're now *using* commit `f668709`.

Running `git rebase --abort` will tell Git to stop the rebasing, and go back to commit `5061c5e`.  This will first erase any unsaved work (!—the assumption here is that your `--abort` flag means *yes, I started this but I want to abandon it forever*), then do a (safe version of) `git checkout` of the commit you *were* on earlier, via `git checkout master`.

---

<sup>4</sup>It might be helpful if Git had a list of "safe" and "unsafe" commands.  Unfortunately, this list is maddening:

- `git checkout` is safe, except it's also unsafe.  This particular insanity resulted in the new `git switch` and `git restore` commands in Git 2.23, to let people split their old `git checkout` habit into two separate commands, one safe and one unsafe.  I have yet to reprogram my own fingers, though, and you might be using an old Git, that only has the all-in-one `git checkout`.
- `git reset` is mostly unsafe, except when you tell it to be safe.
- `git rebase` is almost always mostly safe, though.

Since you're in the middle of a rebase, we can assume safety here.

---

#### There's one more thing to know here

You might think that, with this kind of setup—a *current commit* that holds frozen-forever files, and a working tree where those files have been copied out so that you can work on them—means that when you're working in a Git repository, you always have *two versions of each file* available.  That's true—and that's how a lot of *other* version control systems work—but it doesn't go far enough for Git.

Instead, Git adds a *third* version of each file.  I like to think of this third copy of each file as sitting "between" the frozen, committed copy, which I usually put on the left, and the usable copy, which I put on the right.  This gives us a middle copy.

That middle copy exists in what Git calls, variously, *the index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  Why does this thing have three names?  Probably because *index* doesn't mean anything, and *cache* is too specific.  The term *staging area* reflects the way you, as a human, can and will use it.  That might be the best term for it.  It's also the newest, though, having been invented several years after Git became popular.

When Git first does a `git checkout` of some commit, what it really does is:

- pick *that* commit to be the *current commit*, by attaching the special name `HEAD` to it in some way: you see this in your `git reflog` output, which includes the line:<sup>5</sup>

  ```
  f668709 (HEAD, origin/master)
  ```
- copy that commit's saved files into Git's index / staging-area; and
- copy the saved files into your work-tree, so that you can see and work on them.

The copying, into Git's index and your work-tree, necessitates *removing* from Git's index and your work-tree any files safely stored in some *other* commit.

Now, we know, from the examples of other version control systems, that this index / staging-area thing is not *required*.  The point of this index / staging-area is perhaps to make Git go fast (it does do that), or perhaps the special tricks that it enables (it does enable special tricks).  It's not entirely clear to me what the original point *was*.  The thing about it is that you *cannot ignore it*.  If you try, Git will, now and then, reach out and slap you in the face with it: *Hi there!  You must fuss with my index now!*  So it's necessary to learn to live with it, even if you never end up *liking* it, as long as you'll be using Git.

There is a lot to the index.  In particular, if you are doing a merge (or anything that's sufficiently merge-like) and have *merge conflicts*, Git will *expand* the index so that it's no longer *just* a staging area.

Most of the time, though, a good way to describe Git's index is that it is your *proposed next commit*.  Git simply fills in this proposed *next* commit from the *current* commit.  Then, every time you update some file in your working tree, you need to tell Git: *Copy my updated file back into your index so that I have a different proposal for the **next** commit.*  This is what `git add` does: it makes the index copy of some file, match your working tree copy of that file.

Then, when you run `git commit`, Git can and does just package up whatever files are *in* the index—they're stored, in the index, in the special Git-only form—and those are the files that Git knows about.  That's where the snapshot comes from: it's whatever was in Git's index when you, or whoever, ran `git commit`.

---

<sup>5</sup>This is an odd example, because Git is in what Git calls *detached HEAD* mode.  This mode is used to implement `git rebase`, but it's not a mode you'd normally work in.  Normally `HEAD` would be *attached* instead.  I'm afraid I'm going to skip over most of this here, though.

---

#### Conclusions

As a list of bullet points:

- Git stores *commits*, not files.  The commits then store files.  This makes each commit an all-or-nothing deal, as it were.
- Git *finds* commits by hash ID: the internal commit number.
- Git uses *branch names* to find the *last* (most recent) commit in some chain of commits.  That way you don't normally need to use the big ugly hash IDs.
- In general, Git works by *adding new commits*.  The new commits should point back to the existing commits, so that they add on.  If they *don't* point back, this thing about branch names finding the *last* commit, and Git working backwards from there, stops working.
- The files that are inside a commit are only good as archives (and for diffing, and for all the other things that we can do with frozen-for-all-time files).  To work on / with files, you must *extract* the commit.
- Extracting the commit with `git checkout` fills in both Git's index and your work-tree.  The files you can see and work on / with are in your work-tree, and are *yours*, not *Git's*.  They're not actually *in* the repository: as you change them from what got copied out, Git has no idea about this.
- The fact that your work-tree files aren't *in* Git—they're just next to it—is why you have to `git add`; the fact that `add` only updates the *proposed next commit* is why you have to `git commit`.

Everything else is built atop the above.

Comment: you get the helpful post of the month award! I've been avoiding learning git again because I rarely push code while I build my model. Instead, I've been saving a backup on a portable drive and I'm tired of not being able to git, both the depth of your post and the clarity is showing me I need to go back to re-read "30 days of git".